# differences between solenoid and voice coil

Tags: solenoid

If I replace the movable iron rod of a push/pull solenoid with a movable permanent magnet, does that yield a voice coil or are there any further changes necessary for it to be a voice coil?

Comment: Try researching "rocking armature" loudspeakers and microphones.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different.

A solenoid is a metal rod moving inside a fixed coil. A voice coil is a coil of wire moving in a fixed magnetic field.

To be able to respond to high frequencies (or accelerate fast), the moving part needs to have a low mass. So, although theoretically you could make the body of the solenoid move with a fixed magnet, it will be extremely poor because of the high mass.

Comment: but a permanent magnet moving inside a fixed coil, and a coil moving inside a fixed magnetic field is the same, just different reference frames

Comment: The same but different is still different.

Comment: No, the aren't the same because a solenoid typically doesn't have a permanent magnet inside but a lump of iron.

Comment: @Janka as stated in the question, the lump of iron would be replaced with a permanent magnet